# Free PDF printer without ads

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, printing

I'm looking for a free PDF printer for Windows (7) without any ads, toolbars etc.

Those I checked want to install toolbars, they claim that they are free, but you need to buy them (the *download* is free), etc.

I am looking for one functionality only: PDF printing. I don't want toolbars, I don't want extra functionality, I only want to print PDFs from my applications, without any additional settings.

Comment: Does this PDF are stored in your PC?

Comment: @Aston (S)He does not want to print PDFs, but **to** PDFs.

Comment: It seems you know some that don't match your requirement. Would you mind listing them?

Comment: Example: [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) wants to install a toolbar (click cancel to avoid) and a virus scanner (click Decline to avoid)

Comment: From which source you need to "Print to PDF"? Is it TXT to PDF, Word to PDF??

Comment: @aston, from any app/source. It must be work as a standard printer in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator). I've been using it for years and it does its job very well. It offers advanced features, too, e.g. encryption of the output file.

Comment: I checked this before, it is too complex for simple PDF printing.

Comment: Without ads? That one always wants to install PDF Architect and things.

Comment: Just tried version 2.1.1: wants to install "Ad-Aware Web Companion", "Bing search" and browser tabs. You can click "Cancel" to avoid, but as I understood OP that's exactly what he does not want.

Comment: Well, I always uncheck all the extra options, but I can understand that some people don't even want to be bothered with them.

Comment: I do not believe in these programs anymore. You do not know what else is installed to your computer.

Answer (score 1):

We use [this older version of PDF Creator](http://pchotshots.com/data/clients/mot/Install-PDFCreator.exe), originally from source forge. Installs as a printer, set parameters in registry (clear afterwards) from your program. We haven't yet figured out how to reliably get it to stop prompting for updates though. Link provides a silent install, no toolbars, no extras, no nuthin but a printer.